# Determine if get_the_image has image on Get the image Plugin

Tags: plugins, images, post-thumbnails

is there a way / function to determine if [Get the image](http://wordpress.org/plugins/get-the-image/) plugin successfully grab the image from post? Something like [has_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) on WordPress featured image. I need to know if featured image exist, since other HTML elements (position absolute) / depend on the Featured image for positioning.

Thanks.

Comment: Currently the question is "have plugin. need feature.". Please instead show us what you've tried. See [ask] for more info on how to improve your question-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just run a conditional check on the result of `get_the_image()`. Either it will have returned an image or not.

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) {
  $image = get_the_image(array('echo'=>false));
  if( ! empty ( $image ) ) {
     // do something with the image

  } else {
     // do something if there is no image

  }

}
```

Comment: Hello, it's working. But, when I use $image variable, the image also got printed on post with image. Is there a way to get boolean value out of it like  has_post_thumbnail? I'll use this way for the time being. Thanks.

Comment: You can look at the get the image plugin code to see that `echo` is a function parameter and is true by default, but can be set to false. I've edited my code to show this change. If you're not really comfortable looking at get the image's code, then I'd suggested sticking with the built-in WordPress functions.